# SSL Exception in POCO C++

Tags: c++, exception, https, poco-libraries

When I completed the building POCO library using

```
Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1c.exe
poco-1.4.3p1-all
```

I felt happy first because I could use HTTPS to write my program.However,I encountered a exception

```
msg = "error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

when I use HTTPSClientSession to send a request.My code like following:

```
try{

Context::Ptr pContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, true, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
HTTPSClientSession session(pContext);
Poco::URI uri("...");//private server with https
session.setHost(uri.getHost());
session.setKeepAlive(true);
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST);
session.sendRequest(request) << ...;
char m_arrayRet[1024];
HTTPResponse response;
std::istream& res = session.receiveResponse(response);
while(!res.eof())
res.read(m_arrayRet,1024);
m_arrayRet[res.gcount()] = '\0';
}
catch{
std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
}
```

En,are my codes right ?? It's my first time to use this library.Hope guys to help me,Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Myself have solved this problem.Thank all guys.
The reason about it are that the `443` port were not to be set,and the address is not OK in poco syntax